# Why converting BGR to YCbCr in OpenCV inherit different value compared to manually counting it using equation?

Tags: python, opencv, rgb, ycbcr

I tried to check whether my image conversion have the same RGB value as manually converting using RGB to YCbCr equation. Using python :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

file_src='rgb_color.bmp' //input image
file_dst='ycbcr_color.bmp' //output image

img_src=cv2.imread(file_src,1) //read input image

cv2.namedWindow('src')
cv2.namedWindow('dst')

img_dst=cv2.cvtColor(img_src,cv2.COLOR_BGR2YCrCb)

cv2.imshow('src',img_src)
cv2.imshow('dst',img_dst)
cv2.imwrite(file_dst,img_dst) //write output file as ycbcr_color.bmp
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destoyAllWindows()
```

which succesfully convert [RGB image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gytcb.png) to [supposedly YCrCb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYzoj.png)
(with value of `85 255 76 43 21 150 255 107 29 128 128 255`)
while manually using equation and converting them to image yield me [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtlBj.png)
(with value of `82 90 240 145 54 34 41 240 110 235 128 128`).

Does the fact that OpenCV read RGB as BGR affect this? or does OpenCV read YCbCr as YCrCb (judging at `cv2.COLOR_BGR2YCrCb`)

Comment: You should try `cv2.COLOR_RGB2YCrCb`.

Comment: Tried it and it yields another value which is different from equation result.

Comment: I recommend adding both outputs and the input as well so that people can compare or reproduce the results manually.

Comment: The standard equations for conversion and what OpenCV does is slightly different.  OpenCV calculates scaled and offset versions of the channels.  See https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/de/d25/imgproc_color_conversions.html vs. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr#JPEG_conversion

Comment: @rayryeng Checked both documentation. Does this mean value will always be different as OpenCV and manually checking has different equation?

Answer (score 0):

For future google user:

> The standard equations for conversion and what OpenCV does is slightly different. OpenCV calculates scaled and offset versions of the channels. See docs.opencv.org/3.4/de/d25/imgproc_color_conversions.html vs. en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr#JPEG_conversion – rayryeng